# Return random number 2 value (min max) c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, web-development-server

I need your help. 
i would like to display a random number between two different value of an url parameters.

This is the code. It doesn't work

```
public class RandomIntController : ApiController
{
    public double Get()
    {
        double min = Request.QueryString("min");
        double max = Request.QueryString("max");
        min = 1;
        max = 100;

        Random number = new Random();
        return number.NextDouble();
    }
}
```

So for exemple the guest insert  this url : 
• http://localhost:51832/api/randomint?min=12&max=23

My web api must display a random number between the max value(23) and the min value(12).

I have also several error with the attribut 'resquest.queryString()' :/

[image: REQUEST.QUERYSTRING ERROR]

I don't found my error so please help me

Thank's a lot

Comment: min and max are double or they could be int? Because if you could have then as int you could do random.Next(min, max) and you'll get a number in the desired range.

Comment: Note that you should not create the random instance in the method, because you will get always the same number if you call this method in a loop (so very rapidly). The constructor of random uses the current time as seed. Instead use a field or pass it as parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int min = (int)Request.QueryString["min"];
int max = (int)Request.QueryString["max"];
Random number = new Random();
return number.Next(min, max);
```

`QueryString` is a key value pair, not method. use `[]` instead of `()`. Also pass `min` and `max` as a parameter to `Next` method as in code.

Comment: Note that this will yield random numbers in the range min..max-1 inclusive. If you want to include `max` in the output, do `return number.Next(min, max+1);`

Comment: @MatthewWatson OP says, between, not including.

Comment: "Between" is ambiguous. Does it include the first and last, or exclude the first and last, or include the first and exclude the last? Good to be explicit.

Comment: @Imad your code won't compile because  random.Next(min, max) expects two integers, not doubles. Also Request.QueryString["min"] returns string, so there is a conversion missing there too.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you really need a "double" which includes fractional parts (e.g. 12.443).  If needed, it can be done.  But consider this for integers:

```
  public int Get()
  {
      string minStr = Request.QueryString.Get("min");
      string maxStr = Request.QueryString.Get("max");


      int min = int.Parse(minStr);
      int max = int.Parse(maxStr);

      Random number = new Random();
      int value = number.Next(min, max);
      return value;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `double max` and a `double min` and you want to generate a random number in the range [min, max):

```
Random rng = new Random(); // Declare this once somewhere - don't keep redeclaring it!
double value = min + rng.NextDouble()*(max - min);
```

Note that the random number generated by this will NOT include `max` - [max, min) defines a half-open interval.

If you don't want doubles, then see the answer provided by Imad.